# Rails 3. Date comparison with created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an app in Rails 3 and I would like to do a check that the current user is not new (that it has been more than 24 hours since he signed up). How can I do this?

Thankful for all input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compare the created_at with 24 hours ago:

```
current_user = User.first
if current_user.created_at > 1.day.ago
  # user is new
end
```

Comment: Ah, nice. So if I use < instead I look for users that signed up more than 24 hours ago?

Comment: Yes. `1.day.ago` is a shortcut for `Time.now - (1*24*60*60)` and you are just comparing two timestamps.